# Pass authentication error from factory to controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement Firebase authentication via a factory and I would like to pass the error and even the authData object back to the controller from the factory. Is this possible? I can't seem to figure out how. I keep getting undefined variables.

If I print the error upon a failed login to console.log I get what should be expected, so the rest of this code works. I just can't pass the error/obj back to the controller.

My controller:

```
myApp.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$location', 'Authentication', function($scope, $location, Authentication) {
 $scope.login = function() {
    Authentication.login($scope.user);
    // do something with error from auth factory
 }
}]);
```

My factory:

```
myApp.factory('Authentication', ['$firebase', 'FIREBASE_URL', '$location', function($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, $location){
 var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
 var authObj = {
    login: function(user) {
        return ref.authWithPassword({
            email    : user.email,
            password : user.password
        }, function(error, authData) {
            if (error) {
                // pass error back to controller
                // i've tried the following:
                // authObj.err = error;
                // return authObj.err = error;
            }
            else {
                // pass authData back to controller
            }
        });
    } // login
  };

  return authObj;
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply pass an error handler function to the factory from the controller. Something like this (untested):

```
//Controller
myApp.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$location', 'Authentication', function($scope, $location, Authentication) {
 $scope.login = function() {
    Authentication.login($scope.user, function(error, authData) {
            // access to error
        });
 }
}]);


//Factory
myApp.factory('Authentication', ['$firebase', 'FIREBASE_URL', '$location', function($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, $location){
 var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
 var authObj = {
    login: function(user, errorHandler) {
        return ref.authWithPassword({
            email    : user.email,
            password : user.password
        }, errorHandler);
    } // login
  };

  return authObj;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this in your controller:

```
$scope.login = function() {
    Authentication.login(username, password).then(
        function(result) {
            $location.path('/stuff');
        },
        function(result) {
            $scope.showLoginErrorMessage = true;
        });
};
```

Note that `then()` takes 2 functions as parameters (one for success and one for error). This does depend on how your `Authentication` service works, but it looks OK to me.